# Where to get and how to install (or migrate) missing assemblies for ASP.NET server?

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, server-migration

I am migrating web apps to new hosting servers, but when I try to access them to test on the new server, I get all these assemblies not found errors like:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 28:        <compilation debug="false">
Line 29:            <assemblies>
Line 30:                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
Line 31:                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
Line 32:                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Does anyone know where you find these to install or how to migrate them over?

Comment: Is AJAX installed on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's part of the ASP.Net AJAX kit.

Comment: That's included in the current version, but had to be separately installed on the web server for previous versions.

Comment: You will have to either install the ASP.AJAX kit on the server, or include the assemblies in your project. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273418/any-way-to-use-aspnet-ajax-when-my-server-does-not-and-can-not-have-the-aspnet,

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221761/how-do-i-force-aspnet-ajax-to-use-a-script-from-the-fs-and-not-webresourceaxd-o will say you how you can include the libraries as DLL or as JS.

Comment: Post those links as their own answer and you'll get at least one upvote, stingy.

Comment: BTW: my general SO strategy is to post a 'quick' answer first, and then "flesh it out" with reference links or details once the initial post is up there.  In this case, I was having a much harder time than I thought finding the actual download locations.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either install the ASP.AJAX kit on the server, or include the assemblies in your project. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273418/any-way-to-use-aspnet-ajax-when-my-server-does-not-and-can-not-have-the-aspnet) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221761/how-do-i-force-aspnet-ajax-to-use-a-script-from-the-fs-and-not-webresourceaxd-o) say you how you can include the libraries as DLL or JS.